# How does this op-amp 0-10 V converter work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

This circuit is supposed to be a 0-5 V to 0-10 V/4-20 mA converter.
I know that :

- R7+C1 form an RC filter
- R5+T2+R4 form an inverter to switch between 0-10 V and 4-20 mA in output
- the op-amp is working as a follower

I tried to simulate it in Tina-TI but I didn't get anything in the output.

What do T4 and T1 do? And hoe exactly does the circuit work to provide the 0-10 V/4-20 mA?

[image]

Comment: Without any element values, is a difficult task. And where does this come from? Original schematics + link.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you for your time. I edited the question.

Comment: The circuit you have shown does not generate a 4-20 mA signal. You are mistaken.

Comment: @Andyaka it is supposed to. Can you help me to fix it please

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't. The circuit doesn't work in any way that I can see and I can't recommend anything based on what information you have in your question. Sorry, either you are badly mistaken or you have posted the wrong circuit.

Comment: There are obvious errors as pointed out by others. But I also suspect a problem with "New Macro" being used for T1, T2, and U1. That might mean that these circuit elements are undefined. Even with corrections, this circuit is not a true current source, and output current depends on the load as well as R6, R7, and R8.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that V3 can be 0 V or 3.3 V:

when V3 = 0 V, NMOS T4 is off and NMOS T1 will be on

when V3 = 3.3 V, NMOS T4 is on and NMOS T1 will be off

So with V3 either R3||R2 (|| means they're in parallel) are connected to ground or R8 is connected to ground.

As drawn, R3||R2 **don't do anything useful** as the voltage at the top connection is 5 V due to voltage source V4.

What would make more sense is that R3||R2 connects not to the left of R1 but to the right of R1. Then R1 and R3||R2 are a voltage divider that can be switched on/off with T4

In the same way R6 and R8 are a voltage divider that can be switched on/off with T1.

For large input signals, it might be useful to lower the signal going into the opamp, so voltage divider R1 and R3||R2 would need to be on (T4 is on). Then the voltage divider at the opamp's output can be switched off (T1 is off)

For small input signals it can be the other way round: input voltage divider is off but output voltage divider is on.

> I tried to simulate it in Tina-TI BUT I didn't get anything in the
> output.

What input signal did you apply? In the schematic you show there are only DC signals so there's "nothing to see". There will only be DC voltages. To use a circuit simulator correctly: **THINK** what you think those DC voltage should be, then **verify that** in the simulator. If there's a difference, don't think: "oh, I must be mistaken", instead keep digging until you find a real cause.

Comment: V3 is the output signal selctor. I am trying to simulate the High state where you supposed to get 4-20mA in output (output selector from an MCU Pin) .V4 is an analog input from 0 to 5V.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-assumption: V4 symbolizes the input voltage (0-5V). If not then please OP let me know.

There is a lot of meaningless situations here:

- The output of the opamp will be equal to V4's voltage regardless of the states of T4, T2, and T1. So, if someone says that the circuit converts 0-5V to 0-10V then s/he is dead wrong.
- When T4 is on, the current drawn from V4 can be as high as 40mA. This is a complete waste of power and does not help the conversion(?) process.
- Even if all the other things were correct, the output configuration is not suitable for 20mA output. Just think about the voltage drop across R7 and compare it to the opamp's supply voltage.
- <s>V3 switches on T4, so T4's V<sub>gs-th</sub> is below 3V. So, why would the designer put a presumably different MOSFET (T1) and drive it with 5V? Why is there a separate 5V when 3.3V is enough?</s>

I'm curious about what the designer was smoking when designing this non-useful circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .Yes V4 is the input voltage . I added V3 as DC voltage to simulate the circuit when the state is High (V3 is an output Pin from an MCU to select the output)